# Python: Accessing elements from nested dictionaries a la SQL

Tags: python, dictionary

A simple question - but I haven't found the syntax answer to it yet. How do I select a sub-dictionary that has a specific key-value combination? Effectively, how I `select * where id='ABC'`?

**Details:**

I'm in Python and have created a nested dictionary. I need to pull information from the sub-dictionary where one of the sub-dictionary's key-values is blah.

I've gotten the dictionary initialized and I can read elements of it, but I don't understand how I can call each sub-dictionary by a key value pair. So for example,

```
#json_data is a json object

data={}
for i in range(10):
   data[i]={'id':json_data[i]['id'],
      'stationName':json_data[i]['stationName'], 
      'numBikes':json_data[i]['numBikes']}
```

This gets my nested dictionary started. I can access data as `data[0]` and it will print out my sub-dictionary correctly. But since those indices don't mean anything since I can add/delete lines, I need to access it by a key-value.

But how do I pull up the station name and number of bikes when the id equals "ABC"?

Comment: Why have you created it a nested dictionary? It's keys are just numeric values. I would have added these dictionaries into a list instead.

Comment: What does this have to do with PostgreSQL? Untagging.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the standard python syntax to extract data from dicts. IT might lead to some extra code but it can be done.

But if you need something more fancy or you have so many nested dicts that iteration and looping through is cumbersome, you can try [dpath-python](https://github.com/akesterson/dpath-python) which gives you like a `xpath` kind of interface for querying nested dicts. For SQL kind of syntax I am not sure.

From documentation -

> A python library for accessing and searching dictionaries via
>   /slashed/paths ala xpath
>
> Basically it lets you glob over a dictionary as if it were a
>   filesystem. It allows you to specify globs (ala the bash eglob syntax,
>   through some advanced fnmatch.fnmatch magic) to access dictionary
>   elements, and provides some facility for filtering those results.

Answer (score 0):

Since, as you say, the indices don't mean anything, why not use your id values as keys?

```
data={}
for i in range(10):
    data[json_data[i]['id']] = {
        'stationName': json_data[i]['stationName']
        'numBikes': json_data[i]['numBikes']
    }
```

Or, since we're in python:

```
data = {}
for id, value in json_data.items():
    data[id] = {
        'stationName': value['stationName']
        'numBikes': value['numBikes']
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you just have an array of dictionaries. Is there any more depth to it? If not then it can be as simple as:

```
[data[i] for i in data if data[i]['id']=='ABC']
```